# Spivak Calculus, Chapter 7, Problem 4

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, polynomials

I have (what I think is) a fairly simple question. Spivak's Problem 7-4a asks:

> If $n-k$ is even and greater than or equal to zero, find a polynomial function of degree $n$ with exactly $k$ roots.

Here's the solution in the answer book:

> Let $$l = \frac{n-k}2$$
>
> Let $$f(x) = (x^{2l} + 1)(x - 1)(x-2)\ \cdots\ (x-k)$$

I don't understand why the answer can't just be:

> Let $$f(x) = (x^{n-k} + 1)(x-1)(x-2)\ \cdots\ (x-k)$$

In other words: what role is the $l$ playing?  Also, why do we need to assume that $n-k$ is even?

Comment: If $n-k$ were odd then $x^{n-k} +1$ would have a real root $x=-1$ and thus total number of roots would be greater than $k$.

Answer (score 1):

If $l = \frac{n-k}{2},$ then the two polynomials are the same. Namely,

$f(x) = (x^{2l}+1)(x-1)(x-2)\dots(x-k) = (x^{n-k}+1)(x-1)(x-2)\dots(x-k)$ by substituting the definition of $l.$ However, this is the same polynomial as the one you just describe.

The *role* of using $l,$ in my eyes, is most likely to emphasize the fact that $n-k$ is even. Your solution is completely valid.